# PySpark: Pass value as suffix to dataframe name

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe df and want to add an "iteration suffix". For every iteration, `counter` should be raised by 1 and added as suffix to the dataframe name. For test purposes, my code looks like this:

```
counter = 1
def loop:
    
    counter = counter + 1
    df_%s = df.select('A','B') % counter
```

2 problems here: I don't know how to set up the counter variable as this version runs into an error ('local variable 'counter' referenced before assignment') and I don't know how to correctly pass the current counter value to the dataframe name. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the need to store an information like this? It looks like a need of an historization of your dataframe, and I would recommend you use one single dedicated dataframe with a column that would allow to identify values, probably the date

Comment: Yes, I need to conduct the same operation for a loop over 12 months. Although this might not be the best procedure in PySpark I would really like to know how to do this as I'm coming from SAS and need to transform some SAS scripts into Python (PySpark).

Comment: I understand, but I do not know if there are cases where this syntax is the best one. Unfortunately, I do not know how to proceed nor if it's possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following dataframe

```
+---+------+-----+
|  A|     B|    C|
+---+------+-----+
|  1|   Red| 5.52|
|  2|  Blue| 1.99|
|  3| Green| 3.71|
|  4|Purple|12.09|
+---+------+-----+
```

You can get the result with the following

```
for i in range(0, 9):
    globals()['df_{}'.format(i)] = df.select("A","B")
```

Now you have 10 different dataframes to operate on

```
from pyspark.sql import functions

df_1 = df_1.withColumn("test", functions.lit(1))
df_1.show()

+---+------+----+
|  A|     B|Test|
+---+------+----+
|  1|   Red|   1|
|  2|  Blue|   1|
|  3| Green|   1|
|  4|Purple|   1|
+---+------+----+

df_2.show()
+---+------+
|  A|     B|
+---+------+
|  1|   Red|
|  2|  Blue|
|  3| Green|
|  4|Purple|
+---+------+

#and so on..
```